# Strip symbols and RTTI text from GCC executable

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, rtti

My project uses template metaprogramming heavily. Most of the action happens inside recursive templates which produce objects and functions with very long (mangled) symbol names.

Despite the build time being only ~30 sec, the resulting executable is about a megabyte, and it's mostly symbol names.

On Linux, adding a `-s` argument to GCC brings the size down to ~300 KiB, but a quick look with a text editor shows there are still a lot of cumbersome names in there. I can't find how to strip anything properly on OS X… will just write that off for now.

I suspect that the vtable entries for providing `typeid(x).name()` are taking up a big chunk. Removing all use of the `typeid` operator did not cause anything more to be stripped on Linux. I think that the default exception handler uses the facility to report the type of an uncaught exception.

How might I maximize strippage and minimize these kilobyte-sized symbols in my executable?

Comment: Last I checked g++ uses a string compare for runtime type equality because of some corner cases (e.g. dlopen) where the type_info structs cannot reliably be resolved to the same instances to be checked by identity (pointer compare). These structs cannot be stripped in case some future code (libraries/plugins/etc) need the type_info. I will double check the code and report back later if I remembered correctly.

Comment: Programs (as opposed to libraries) are usually not mean for dlopening, though.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: programs can potentially use `dlopen` to load a library and you end up with the exact same issue looking from the other side.

Comment: Correct but if any part of your program or any of its dependencies could dlopen then you are in the same situation. There is really no definitive way to know if the data is needed so the compiler has to play safe.

Comment: Oh, ok then. Pretend I didn't say anything.

Comment: Well… is there a "bigger hammer" out there that can just get rid of this crud? `dlopen` is a significant use case to be sure but a lot of developers just don't want their symbols out in the wild.

Comment: Might want to look at http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility to see if it can help you.

Comment: dlopen is not the only corner case but never the less. type_info does indeed appear to use string comparisons type equality (although it does short circuit on identity for speed). What I haven't checked is how dynamic_cast works buy I remember reading a while back that it walks the type_info tree for a match which would mean the name cannot be removed. There is a similar question for msvc on stack overflow with the same problem and that mentions it being possible with an old version of gcc but I think that was before the switch to string compare.

Comment: I don't even care about completely removing the type_info names, but could just replace them will null-terminated hashes or serial IDs to satisfy the string comparison for type equality construct. IMO the ABI is defective if it mandates that my symbols go into the binary. With all these recursive templates and lambdas, a single type name can recapitulate the entire program structure, which should be a secret.

Answer (score -2):

Just run the program `strip` on the final executable.  If you want to be fancier, you can use some other tools to store the debug info separately, but for your stated purpose, just `strip a.out` is fine.  Maybe use the `--strip-all` option--I haven't tried that myself to see if it differs from the default behavior.

If you really want to try disabling RTTI, well, it's `gcc -fno-rtti`.  But that may break your program badly--only one way to find out I guess.

Comment: `strip` does the same thing as `g++ -s`. I do make liberal use `dynamic_cast`, so I need RTTI, but this shouldn't require mangled names.

Comment: Have you tried the various options to strip, like `--strip-all`?  (I added a mention of it just before you wrote your above comment, but you probably didn't see it before).

Comment: `--strip-all` (a.k.a. `-s`) seems to be the default. This is basically what I'm looking for insight into.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable contribution, Abyx.  We are enlightened.